# Can't include separate lines in my comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown

When I am posting a comment, I can't seem to write on multiple lines. If I hit alt+enter it goes to a new line on my screen, but when I post the comment it all appears on one line. How on earth do I format my comments?

Comment: it worked when i hit enter for my original post but now i cant type on multiple lines when posting a comment unless i just keep typing and it does it naturally but I want to be able to write sql code and have the select from and where all on different lines for readability.

Comment: @donal thats for answers, not comments, no?

Comment: I will try and close  this now

Comment: @Twelfth ok, here is the topic on formatting comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments

Comment: @Amicheals Which formattings in particular? Comments markup is restricted for several kinds of formatting (e.g. multi paragraph/line breaks aren't supported).

Comment: ***Good!*** Site that have MathJax running have a hack that makes that happen and it is *awful*---distracting and creates huge amounts of space.

Comment: @dmckee you mean you [don't like](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409372/solve-laplace-equation-in-the-upper-half-plane/409419#comment878838_409419) [pimped](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472013/if-the-curve-with-equation-y-x3px2-4-is-the-tangent-on-long-axis-find-th/472036#comment1016241_472036) [comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396156/level-sets-questions/396163#comment848134_396163)?

Answer (score 3):

Comments markup formatting is restricted in several ways (no multiple paragraphs or explicit line breaks in particular!).
If you click the `help` link right beneath the comment edit box, the it shows:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[link](http://example.com)` `_italic_` `**bold**` `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. [Learn more ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

The latter link provides even more detail about comment formatting features.

---

If you need to clarify something for your question or answer, that requires more sophisticated formatting (code especially), please edit your post by adding this information as an update to the original.